# docker cp to container: file name too long

Tags: docker, cp

I am trying to `docker cp` a directory and everything inside to a container but I am getting this error:

```
$ docker cp clink 2eca:.
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): open /clink/jobs/target/streams/$global/assemblyOption/$global/streams/assembly/82b354e42adbb42665af515b27b02de840e038ee_2df49b1995a6c8135f35e880f8876f7513ab872d_da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709/org/scalacheck/ArbitraryArities$$anonfun$arbTuple11$1$$anonfun$apply$99$$anonfun$apply$100$$anonfun$apply$101$$anonfun$apply$102$$anonfun$apply$103$$anonfun$apply$104$$anonfun$apply$105$$anonfun$apply$106$$anonfun$apply$107$$anonfun$apply$108$$anonfun$apply$109.class: file name too long
```

I am pretty new to docker to I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it

Posted issue onto dockers githug:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/31353

Comment: It looks like a bug to me.  Which version are you using?

Comment: @RicardoBranco `$ docker -v
Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3`

Comment: It is definitely a bug.  I created a void file with the same pathname in /tmp and tried to copy it to a container and got the same error.

Comment: Do you want to file a bug in Github?

Comment: @RicardoBranco yes i can do that

Comment: Great. Please post the Github issue here for us to follow.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a bug.  It doesn't happen on 1.12.2.

Thanks for opening the issue:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/31353

Comment: There's a problem with the AUFS storage driver too.  I've tested with the overlay and overlay2 drivers (on Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.8) and the issue didn't appear.